# Leiningen how to include dependency into result jar file

Tags: clojure, leiningen

```clj
(defproject dumortierite "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
 
  ;; omitted...

  :dependencies [
                 [com.github.freeze-dolphin/clamp "4ddd923dcb" :scope "compile"]

                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.11.1" :scope "provided"]
                 [io.papermc.paper/paper-api "1.19.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT" :scope "provided"]
                 [com.github.StarWishsama/Slimefun4 "2023.02" :scope "provided"]
                ])
```

I've added 4 dependencies, and I want to include only
`[com.github.freeze-dolphin/clamp "4ddd923dcb" :scope "compile"]`
in the build result jar

if using `lein uberjar`, it will contain all of these 4 deps in the jar.

i know this could be done by using `shade` in `maven`, but how in `leiningen`?

---

I've tried below:

```clj
:dependencies [[com.github.freeze-dolphin/clamp "4ddd923dcb"]]
  :profiles {:dev
             {:dependencies
              [
               [com.github.freeze-dolphin/clamp "4ddd923dcb" :scope "compile"]
               ]}
             :provided
             {:dependencies
              [
               [org.clojure/clojure "1.11.1" :scope "provided"]
               [io.papermc.paper/paper-api "1.19.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT" :scope "provided"]
               [com.github.StarWishsama/Slimefun4 "2023.02" :scope "provided"]
               ]}}
```

but in `jar`, no deps is contained.
and in `uberjar`, everything is contained...

Comment: Putting things in the `:provided` profile, should prevent them from
showing up in the uberjar. Could it be, that the two undesired deps are
also (transitive) deps from your `clamp` lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use `:uberjar-exclusions` in your `project.clj` with a vector of regular expressions that will be used to match the filenames in the project. Any match will cause the file **not** to be packed in the Uberjar.

I tested it on a sample project with the following dependencies:

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.11.1" :scope "provided"]
                 [commons-codec/commons-codec "1.15"]]
```

To exclude the files from `commons-codec` from the Uberjar, I used:

```
:profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all
                     :uberjar-exclusions [#"org/apache/commons/codec"
                                          #"META-INF/maven/commons-codec"]
                     :jvm-opts ["-Dclojure.compiler.direct-linking=true"]}}
```

The original example is in the [sample project.clj](https://codeberg.org/leiningen/leiningen/src/branch/stable/sample.project.clj#L435) from Leiningen.